# i have created dynamically addrows invoice had discount textbox for allrows if ichange discount it is updated on first row not all rows updated

Tags: html, jquery, html-table, datatable, invoice

I am new to jQuery and HTML tables created in jQuery table dynamically add row if I update discount input all rows in column should be updated
but my firs row is updated other rows are not updated

[before discount change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRnPB.jpg)

After change value in discount it shows like this:

[after discount change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdNur.jpg)

My code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          
          <div class="line line-dashed line-lg pull-in"></div>
          <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="orders">
              <td><input class="form-control discount" type='number' data-type="discount" id='discount' name='discount[]' for="1"/></td>
              <th>discount</th>
              <tr>
                
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Total </th>
                <th>Net Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Net Total </th>
                <th>
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input class="form-control product_price" type='number' data-type="product_price" id='product_price_1' name='product_price[]' for="1"/></td> <!-- purchase_cost -->
                <td><input class="form-control quantity" type='number' id='quantity_1' value= '1' name='quantity[]' for="1"/></td>
                <td><input class="form-control total_cost" type='text' id='total_cost_1' name='total_cost[]' for='1' readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="form-control less_price" type='number' data-type="less_price" id='less_price_1' name='less_price[]' for="1"readonly/></td> <!-- purchase_cost -->
                <td><input class="form-control less_quantity" type='number' id='less_quantity_1' name='less_quantity[]' for="1"readonly/></td>
                <td><input class="form-control less_total" type='text' id='less_total_1' name='less_total[]' for='1' readonly/></td>
                <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success circle">+</button></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <input class="form-control" type='hidden' data-type="product_id_1" id='product_id_1' name='product_id[]'/>            
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="line line-dashed line-lg pull-in" style="clear: both;"></div>
        
        <div class="col-md-12 ">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 pull-left ">
            <div class="col-md-8 pull-left ">
              <div class="form-group">
                <tr>
                  <th>sub Total </th>
                <td><input class="form-control subtotal" type='text' id='subtotal' name='subtotal' readonly/></td>
                <th>Net Total </th>
                <td><input class="form-control lessgtotal" type='text' id='lessgtotal' name='lessgtotal' readonly/></td>
              </tr>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-3 pull-left">
              <div class="form-group">
               
                <div>
                
              
                 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
{
  
  var rowCount = 1;
  
  $('#add').click(function() {
    rowCount++;
    $('#orders').append('<tr id="row'+rowCount+'"><td><input class="form-control product_price" type="number" data-type="product_price" id="product_price_'+rowCount+'" name="product_price[]" for="'+rowCount+'"/></td><input class="form-control" type="hidden" data-type="product_id" id="product_id_'+rowCount+'" name="product_id[]" for="'+rowCount+'"/><td><input class="form-control quantity" type="number" class="quantity" id="quantity_'+rowCount+'" name="quantity[]" value="1" for="'+rowCount+'"/> </td><td><input class="form-control total_cost" type="text" id="total_cost_'+rowCount+'" name="total_cost[]"  for="'+rowCount+'" readonly/> </td> id="row'+rowCount+'"><td><input class="form-control less_price" type="number" data-type="less_price" id="less_price_'+rowCount+'" name="less_price[]" for="'+rowCount+'"readonly/></td><input class="form-control" type="hidden" data-type="product_id" id="product_id_'+rowCount+'" name="product_id[]" for="'+rowCount+'"/><td><input class="form-control less_quantity" type="number" class="less_quantity" id="less_quantity_'+rowCount+'" name="less_quantity[]" for="'+rowCount+'"readonly/> </td><td><input class="form-control less_total" type="text" id="less_total_'+rowCount+'" name="less_total[]"  for="'+rowCount+'" readonly/> </td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+rowCount+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove cicle">-</button></td></tr>');
   });
}




// Add a generic event listener for any change on quantity or price classed inputs
$("#orders").on('input', 'input.quantity,input.product_price', function() {
  getTotalCost($(this).attr("for"));
});

$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
  var button_id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
});


// Using a new index rather than your global variable i
function getTotalCost(ind) {
  var qty = $('#quantity_'+ind).val();
  var price = $('#product_price_'+ind).val();
  var totNumber = (qty * price);
  var tot = totNumber.toFixed(2);
  $('#total_cost_'+ind).val(tot);
  calculateSubTotal();
}

function calculateSubTotal() {
  var subtotal = 0;
  $('.total_cost').each(function() {
     subtotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
  });
  $('#subtotal').val(subtotal);
}





// Add a generic event listener for any change on discount
$("#orders").on('input', 'input.discount,input.product_price', function() {
getdiscountCost($(this).attr("for"));
});

$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
  var button_id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
});


// Using a dicount formula  
function getdiscountCost(ind) {
  var dis = $('#discount').val();
  var price = $('#product_price_'+ind).val();
  var disc = ((100 - dis) /100 )
  var atotNumber = (disc * price);
  var atot = atotNumber.toFixed(2);
  $('#less_price_'+ind).val(atot);
  
}

// this code used copy to less quantity

$("#orders").on('input', 'input.quantity,input.product_price', function() {
  copyqty($(this).attr("for"));
});

// formulafor copy quantity
function copyqty(ind) {
  
  var nqty = $('#quantity_'+ind).val();
 
  var tqty = (nqty * 1);
  var lqty = tqty.toFixed(0);
  $('#less_quantity_'+ind).val(lqty);
  
}


//Add a generic event listener for any change on discount on  LESS TOTAL
$("#orders").on('input', 'input.quantity,input.product_price', function() {
getdiscounttotal($(this).attr("for"));
});

$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() { 
  var button_id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
});



// Using a dicount formula for LESS TOTAL 
function getdiscounttotal(ind) {
  var tdis = $('#discount').val();
  var tprice = $('#total_cost_'+ind).val();
  var tdisc = ((100 - tdis) /100 )
  var btotNumber = (tdisc * tprice);
  var btot = btotNumber.toFixed(2);
  $('#less_total_'+ind).val(btot);
 
}

//Add a generic event listener for any change on discount on  LESS GRAND TOTAL
$("#orders").on('input', 'input.discount,input.product_price', function() {
getlessgtotal($(this).attr("for"));
});

$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() { 
  var button_id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
});



// Using a dicount formula for LESS GRAND TOTAL 
function getlessgtotal(ind) {
  var lgdis = $('#discount').val();
  var lgprice =$ ('#subtotal').val();
  var lgdisc = ((100 - lgdis) /100 )
  var ctotNumber = (lgdisc * lgprice);
  var ctot = ctotNumber.toFixed(2);
  $('#lessgtotal').val(ctot);
}
</script>
```

subtotal and nettotal are updated but not dynamically added rows updating
thanks in advance